# Problem with rotating the values on the x-axis by 90 on the graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I make three graphs using matplotlib library. I try to rotate x-axis values by 90 using
`plt.xticks(rotation=90)`. This work well on two graphs but the last one is more complicated. This is the code for the last graph:

```
    %matplotlib inline
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    
    color = 'tab:red'
    ax1.set_xlabel('Rok')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Liczba loch', color=color)
    ax1.plot(rok, lochy, color=color,marker="D")
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    color = 'tab:blue'
    ax2.set_ylabel('Liczba knurów', color=color)
    ax2.plot(rok, knury, color=color,marker = "o")
    ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
    plt.title(f"Liczba użytkowanych knurów i loch w województwie\n {wojewodztwo}, w stadzie {stado} na przestrzeni lat")
    plt.grid()
    fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
    plt.xticks(np.arange(min(rok), max(rok)+1))
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.savefig('wykres.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

This whole graph works very well, the only problem is this rotation.
Now my graph looks like this:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Move the plt.xticks(...) before the `twinx()` line...

Answer (score 1):

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(rok, rotation=90)
```